# I need to find substring index in string and if doesn`t exist returned result must be -1 in Java (web service)

Tags: java, string, web-services

I must create function that is checking if sub string is contained in string.I need the index of that sub string.It will be used in JAX-WS client + service.
I have to use ready WSDL file. So the problem is that if I use indexOf I receive error that saying string can not be int.

```
public int findSubstr(java.lang.String text, java.lang.String substr) {
    int position = findSubstr.indexOf(substr , text)
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented yet.");
}
```

The string and searched sub string are hard coded in client side by that way

```
<%
try {
client.test.app.TextManipulation_Service service = new client.test.app.TextManipulation_Service();
client.test.app.TextManipulation port = service.getTextManipulationPort();
 // TODO initialize WS operation arguments here
java.lang.String text = "Some string here";
java.lang.String substr = "string";
// TODO process result here
int result = port.findSubstr(text, substr);
out.println("Result = "+result);
} catch (Exception ex) {
// TODO handle custom exceptions here
}
%>
```

so I can't get the idea how to use indexOf for that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try this and see if it helps?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String text = "Some string here";
    String substr = "string";
    if(text.contains(substr)) {
        int index =  text.indexOf(substr);
        System.out.println(index);
    }
}
```

Your method can be rewritten like:

```
   public static int findSubstr (String source, String substr) {
        if(source.contains(substr)) {
            int index =  source.indexOf(substr);
            return index;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

The method `contains` will check whether `substr` is there in the `source` `String` and if it is there returns the index.